# Schema for type TypeTag[java.sql.Timestamp] is not supported when creating Spark Dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have the following code which tries to create DataFrame from Seq[T]

```
case class CaseConvert[T: TypeTag](a: T)

def createDf[T: TypeTag](data: Seq[T]): DataFrame = {
   spark.createDataFrame(data.map(CaseConvert[T])
}
```

When above createDf method executed by passing type say Seq[java.sql.Timestamp] it fails showing the following error

> UnsupportedOperaionException: Schema for type TypeTag[java.sql.Timestamp] is not supported

I think I have to create encoder for CaseConvert class but not sure how to do it using complex generics of Scala. I am new to Spark and Scala.

Comment: Why don't you simply `spark.createDataFrame(Seq(1,2,3).map(CaseConvert.apply))`, i.e. forget about `TypeTag` and simply use `CaseConvert.apply` (without `[T]` at execution time)?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `Encoder` like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

val spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._

case class CaseConvert[T](a: T)

def createDf[T:  TypeTag](data: Seq[T])(implicit e: Encoder[T]): DataFrame = {
   spark.createDataFrame(data.map(CaseConvert(_)))
}

createDf(Seq(new java.sql.Timestamp(1)))
//org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: timestamp]
```

will be enough here. Implicit resolution for `Products` will do the rest.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_type  / http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.12/#scala.Product

Comment: After adding T: Encoder: TypeTag I get the same error UnsupportedOperationException Schema for type TypeTag[java.sql.Timestamp] is not supported